# Automatic code operation without pressing on button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry for the basic question, but I just started learning JS. Sorting occurs after clicking on the button, but how to make it automatically during opening the page? Thanks.

```
<button onclick="sortTable()">Sort</button>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Spain</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
function sortTable() {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      shouldSwitch = false;
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
      if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to sort your table automatically when page is loaded? Just call your function `sortTable()` on the first line of your `script` and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run your function as soon as the DOM is ready by calling a function on document load.

```
document.onload = function() {
    sortTable();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This could answer your question and at the same time could help others who is looking run a button click after load, even though you can just type the function() on the document ready , this is one of the ways how to trigger a button click after page load and run its function, You can use the following Code I posted a full html and javascript code, as i also included the jquery link, this will trigger the button click upon the completion of document load,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<button id='btn1' onclick="btnFuntion()">Test</button>

    <script>

    $(document).ready(()=>{
        document.getElementById('btn1').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click"));
    })


    function btnFuntion(){
        alert("the button has been clicked Automatically")
        //this is the button function you can put your code here..
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

good luck, don't forget to mark it answered if its useful... so it could be useful for others... :)